# React useRef reset current value when component unmouted

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a useRef hook to refer to two components, but I am facing a problem that if either of those components unmounted then useRef won't work.

Code below:

```
const ref = useRef();

const handleFocusInput = () => {
  ref.current.focus();
}

// both input components use the same useRef() hook
<Input ref={ref} onFocusInput={handleFocusInput} /> 


// Modal will be destroyed on close and the Input component inside Modal will be destroyed as well
<Modal onClose={() => setCloseModal()}> 
  <Input ref={ref} onFocusInput={handleFocusInput} />
</Modal>
```

Input component:

```
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   return (
     <>
       <button onClick={props.onFocusInput}>Click to focus input</button>
       <input ref={ref} type="text" />
     </>
   )
})
```

When I closing Modal, the `current.value` of useRef() will be reset to undefined and so it causing an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')` when I am clicking to the button in Input to trigger onFocusInput.

I want to keep `ref` still working even if one of them Input component is destroyed. How I can resolved it?

Comment: You can't keep it alive because it's no longer existing after the modal is dismounted. Your goal should be to salvage the value property value instead, either after it's been changed or before the modal will unmount.

Comment: How it makes sense to have same ref for two inputs? It not really works as you expect, the ref value will be the last rendered component. I think what you trying to achieve is having 3 refs, 2 for inputs and one "merged"

Comment: You should explain whats the actual problem, see https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @DennisVash What is one for "merged" ? can you give me a sample code as an example?

Comment: @DennisVash the actual problem is I want to create a Post component with comment Input, and when I clicking to attachment photos and it will show an modal with the same Post component inside that modal , you can imagine it like a Facebook post in the timeline

Comment: So why you need two inputs? Render a single same input twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on solving your problem and not the code, I think you want a single Input component instead:

```
const inputRef = useRef();

const handleFocusInput = () => {
  inputRef.current.focus();
};

const input = <Input ref={inputRef} onFocusInput={handleFocusInput} />;

<>
  {input}
  <Modal onClose={() => setCloseModal()}>{input}</Modal>
</>
```